# Give a Linear Gauge custom labels

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a kendo linear gauge defined like this...

```
$("#gauge").kendoLinearGauge({

    pointer: {
        value: 4.5,
        shape: "arrow"
    },

    scale: {
        majorUnit: 1,
        minorUnit: 1,
        max: 6,
        ranges: [
            {
                from: 0,
                to: 1,
                color: "#ffc700"
            }, {
                from: 1,
                to: 2,
                color: "#ff7a00"
            }, {
                from: 2,
                to: 3,
                color: "#c20000"
            }, {
                from: 3,
                to: 4,
                color: "#FF0000"
            }, {
                from: 4,
                to: 5,
                color: "#00FF00"
            }, {
                from: 5,
                to: 6,
                color: "#0000FF"
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

And this produces a gauge that looks like this...

[image]

What I want to do is replace the numeric labels with string values like "Unverified", "Verified", "Open", etc so that I end up with something more akin to this...[image]

I'm fairly confident that I *should* be able to do this using a template, but I can't get even the simplest of examples (including the one shown below from the telerik website) to work.

```
$("#linear-gauge").kendoLinearGauge({
     scale: {
         labels: {
             // labels template
             template: "#= value #%"
         }
     }
});
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a template function

```
template: function (rec) {
    var label;
    switch (rec.value) {
        case 0:
            label = 'un verified';
            break;
        case 1:
            label = 'verified';
            break;
        default:
            label = 'open';
    }
    return label;
}
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/@harsh/EgeVa

Comment: can you repost your dojo example please? I looked at it on Friday from home and it was there and working, this morning (granted from my office computer) it's empty.

Comment: Thx. TBH I'm not sure if the IT nazis at head office are making it difficult for me to see or if it has actually disappeared! :-)

Comment: So I saw when I got home. It must be group IT again. Thanks for checking.